# How to setup remote encrypted dir with conflict handling?

Tags: 12.04, sync, encryption

Is it possible to setup a remote server to store a folder with encrypted contents, which is impossible to read by the server, but is editable by multiple clients?

It seems like duplicity is a tool for this, but I'm not sure if any data loss is possible if 2 workstations try to edit the same file simultaneously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that **ownCloud** will probably do what you're looking for.

If you can't/don't want to run **ownCloud**, and want to roll your own solution, you'll need:

(1) a capable revision control system to deal with conflicts, like **git**, **hg** or **bzr**;

(2) encryption tools like **TrueCrypt**, **eCryptFS** or **Duplicity**;

(3) a method of accessing the file server, such as **FTP** or **SSH**; and

(4) a number of complex hand-crafted **shell scripts** to tie the whole thing together.

Comment: The screenshots show that the files *are* readable on the server, aren't they?

Comment: I'm not sure of the details and the options available, but it sounds like (with encryption enabled), your data will be stored encrypted, and will be encrypted on the wire, but yes, it does look like the files do end up unencrypted in the sever's RAM for a short period of time once you've sent it your password. You could of course use ownCloud's versioning/sync features and combine them with eCryptFS for de-/encryption on the clients.